# How to synchronously respond from an Azure Function when my response data is obtained via a webhook?

Tags: azure-functions, webhooks

I have an HTTP triggered Azure function (function A) used to respond to a webhook.

The issue that I am having right now is that now within my Azure function I need to call an API to get the response data, but this new API just receives my request and sends me an ACK response, and the real response from this API is sent via webhook.

I can create another HTTP triggered Azure function (function B) to receive the data from the new API, but how can I communicate this data to my original Azure function (function A) to synchronously respond.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.